# How to set up the Typesafe stack on FreeBSD 9?

Tags: scala, freebsd, typesafe-stack

I'm eager to get into Scala through the Typesafe stack, but cannot get it up and running on FreeBSD 9.0 stable. Specifically, I'm having trouble with giter8 (cannot install via conscript).

Do you have any idea how to go about this ? (I'm using the 'universal' tar installation from typesafe.com) and linux-sun-jdk17 package on FreeBSD.

Comment: Please provide more information. Why don't you paste the last few lines of the session, or the whole session if it's not too long?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not familiar with Scala, but in general installing any software on FreeBSD is best done via ports. For Scala there is already a port [lang/scala](http://www.freshports.org/lang/scala), which should be your first step:

```
% cd /usr/ports/lang/scala
% make install clean
```

Good luck!